# wordpress show a limited number of category in category widget

Tags: wordpress, loops, tabs, categories

I want to show a limited number of category in my category widget. E.g You are think a tab and first page of tab is showed ten category names and second page of tab is showed fife category names.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use forloop for each tab and display the categories or you can use like this

```
<?php
$category = get_the_category(); 
echo $category[0]->cat_name;
?>
```

May be you can use like this function in wordpress

```
<?php wp_list_categories('orderby=name&include=3,5,9,16'); ?>
```

Where 3,5,9 are included categories and also